# Chrome Extensions - Can I automate downloading with them?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I posted this basic question on Chrome's Support boards, but no replys thus far. I have also noticed a couple threads asking about Extensions that would have a basic functionality from my question... But judging as none have been made so far, I am starting to doubt if it is possible in the current build of Chromium.

Anyways...
I have an extension that I would like to be able to start image downloads, and maybe even choose where they can be downloaded to. Like say theres a bunch of images on the page, I want to be able to scan all the image urls, and download them to a folder.

I have looked over the HTML5 FileSystem API, but I do not believe this would suite my needs as it would saves these files to a "Sandbox" folder that would be buried somewhere on the file system. And if a non-technical user were to use my extension, that would be troublesome for them to locate the now downloaded files.

Comment: This guy has a lot about file system and Chrome. It was written back in Chrome 9 days, but he has updates referencing Chrome 12 - http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/

Comment: Again the HTML5 FileSystem API stores file locally at a 5 MB limit per website.

Google Quote: "The implementation now obfuscates paths on disk, so you can't see your filesystem under the profile directory any more.  This is a security-driven change, but also allows us to make the API more powerful and portable. The files are still there, but their names are now just consecutive numbers, and the directories aren't visible at 
all."

Sounds like they are making the API something similar to Cookies. Where files only useful to the website are stored, and not suitable for giving files to users.

Comment: Take a look at NPAPI plugins then. You can load your own dll's and you are not sandboxed. Although if you plan on distributing the plugin through Chrome Store you will need to jump through hoops. http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/npapi.html

Comment: mrtsherman is right, Chrome extensions don't have access to the file system - they are always sandboxed. You should be able to trigger a "Save As" dialog for each image but that's already it. The only way around are NPAPI plugins (which you will have to compile for each operating system and you will also get a big and ugly warning message on install).